# OutputIterator return from std::copy

Tags: c++, c++11

The equivalent of the function template std::copy is :

```
template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
 OutputIterator copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result)
{
   while (first!=last) {
   *result = *first;
   ++result; ++first;
}
return result;
}
```

Which is used on this code:

```
int * n = new int[3]{1,2,3};
int * m = new int[3]{4,5,6};
std::vector<int> asd;

std::copy(n,n+1,std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(asd,asd.begin()));
```

***From my understanding:***
One thing i noticed is the: `OutputIterator` return type from the template which is based from the 3rd argument of the copy. In this case, `std::insert_iterator` will return a `std::vector<int>` which is also going to be the return type of the `std::copy`

My question

When is the `OutputIterator` received?
The code has been fired up by:

```
std::copy(n,n+1,std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(asd,asd.begin()))
```

so when the function ends, isn't it supposed to return the same type as the third argument which is `std::vector<int>` ?

Corrections will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `std::insert_iterator` can be created more conveniently via [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) (which deduces the container's type).

Comment: *"std::insert_iterator will return a std::vector<int>"* `std::insert_iterator` is a class template. How could it *return* something?

Comment: I mean, the `OutputIterator` return type from the `std::copy` will be based of the 3rd argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned iterator refers to just beyond the end of the destination range that's copied. In the case of a back insert iterator, it'll also be a back_insert_iterator, so writing to it will add an element to the end of the destination collection.

For example, code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> s{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> d;

    auto i = std::back_inserter(d);

    i = std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), i);
    *i = 5;

    std::copy(d.begin(), d.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));
}
```

should produce an output of:

```
1       2       3       5
```

The official wording from the standard sort of assumes something like random access iterators (§25.3.1/2):

> Returns: result + (last - first)

...where `result` is the iterator passed as the destination, `first` is the beginning of the source range, and `last` is the end of the source range.

Comment: How do i correctly receive get? because i get an error if it's   `std::vector<int>::iterator get;`
  
  `get = std::copy(n,n+1,std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(asd,asd.begin()));`

Comment: Unless you're masochistic, I'd advise doing it as above (using `auto`). Iterators were the poster-boys for `auto`. If you really insist on doing things the hard way, the type of the result should exactly match the type of the third argument you pass to `copy` (in your case, I believe that should be `std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>`).

Comment: One last, so `auto get = std::copy(n,n+1,std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(asd,asd.begin()));`  what will get become? the third argument is an iterator, so how do i exactly access it?

Comment: @CarloBrew: As shown in the sample code in my answer, you can write to it via `*get = whatever;`. Since it's an OutputIterator, you can also increment it. You can't really do a whole lot beyond that.

Comment: The standard has blanket wording ([algorithms.general]/p12) saying that `-` means `std::distance` and `+` means (essentially) `std::next` for non-random-access-iterators.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong with this assumption:

> *"as the third argument which is `std::vector<int>`"*

It's actually `std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Is the `std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>` meant to be received when the `std::copy` function ends? or more like who receives it / what's the purpose?

Comment: @CarloBrew Yes. You could write much simpler like this: `std::copy(n,n+1,asd.begin())`. But the return value is a `std::vector<Int>::iterator` then.

Comment: It worked when i did `get = std::copy(n,n+1,asd.begin());`  but i get errors if it's `get = std::copy(n,n+1,std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(asd,asd.begin()));`   wherein get is an `std::vector<int>::iterator get;`    what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>(asd,asd.begin())
```

is a call of contsructor of iterator adapter `std::insert_iterator`. So it will be returned from algorithm std::copy.

For example consider the following code snippet

```
int * n = new int[3]{1,2,3};
int * m = new int[3]{4,5,6};
std::vector<int> asd;

std::copy( m, m + 3,
           std::copy( n, n + 3,
                      std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>( asd, asd.begin() ) ) );
```

At first all elements of the first dynamically allocated array will be inserted into the vector and then the insertion in the vector will continue using elements of the second dynamically allocated array.

The same could be done the following way

```
std::vector<int> asd( n, n + 3 );
asd.insert( asd.end(), m, m + 3 );
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the both code snippets in action

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
{   
    int * n = new int[3]{1,2,3};
    int * m = new int[3]{4,5,6};
    std::vector<int> asd;

    std::copy( m, m + 3,
               std::copy( n, n + 3,
                          std::insert_iterator<std::vector<int>>( asd, asd.begin() ) ) );

    for ( int x : asd ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete []n;
    delete []m;
}
{   
    int * n = new int[3]{1,2,3};
    int * m = new int[3]{4,5,6};
    std::vector<int> asd( n, n + 3 );

    asd.insert( asd.end(), m, m + 3 );  

    for ( int x : asd ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete []n;
    delete []m;
}   
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6
```